# DFS Algorithm implementation using C++ STL

Tags: c++, graph-traversal

I have recently learnt DFS algorithm and tried to implement using C++ and STL concept.But while running the code with gcc it is giving me some error.Could someone please advice where the mistake has been done at my end?

The error is

> exited with code=3221225477 in 2.75 seconds

Please find below the full code below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void addEdge(vector<int> adj[], int u, int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v); //singly linked ,not bidirectional
}

void DFS(vector<int> adj[], int v, vector<bool> &vis)
{
    vis[v] = true;
    cout << v << " ";
    //for(int i=0;i<adj[v].size() ; i++)
    for (auto i : adj[v])
    {
        //if(!vis[adj[v][i]])
        if (vis[i] == false)
            DFS(adj, i, vis);
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> adj[5];
    vector<bool> visited(5, false);
    addEdge(adj, 1, 2);
    addEdge(adj, 1, 3);
    addEdge(adj, 2, 4);
    addEdge(adj, 3, 5);
    addEdge(adj, 4, 5);
    DFS(adj, 1, visited);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following bugs in your code

1. `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. Do not use this header. Use the needed C++ headers
2. `using namespace std;` Do not use this. Use qualified names
3. `vector<int> adj[5];` fo never and under no circumstances use plain C-Style arrays. In your case you need a vector of vector
4. Both of your vector/array dimensions are one to small.

You add edge numbers up to 5. But your array/vector has only 5 elements. In C++ array indices start counting with 0. So, a vector v with 5 elements has element v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4]. If you try to access the index 5, you will have an out of bounds error. The program will crash.

The `std::vector`'s at() function will also be your friend.

Simply increase array sizes.

```
  vector<int> adj[6];                  // 6 elements needed
  vector<bool> visited(6, false);      // 6 elements needed
```

Comment: For the first two points, it really depends on your context. In a programming context, it doesn't apply, you can simply look at the world champions' solutions.

Comment: @armin Montigny , Thanks a lot for the lightening , clear and detailed response I was trying to debug the code since past two days.I will keep all the suggestion offered.Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @L.Meyer in contests people use that because it saves time. In real code you'll quickly regret after using them. \@Armin `never and under no circumstances use plain C-Style arrays` sometimes you'll need C-style arrays to avoid heap allocation, although that should be replaced by `std::array`